# How to disable caching in http request on windows mobile 2005?

Tags: http, session, caching, connection, request

I use Visual Studio 2008 (C++ smart device application).
I have successfully established the connection and sent requests. But I don't know how to disable the caching (it doesn't work or stops the application as with an exception.
I cannot use the debugging because I need to disconnect from ms device center (because of some internet ports are working directly via wi-fi only.

An approximate code:

```
CInternetSession session = ...;
CInternetConnection *pConnection = ...;
CHttpFile *pFile = ...;

pConnection = session.GetHttpConnection(server, port);
pFile = pConnection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, requestString);
pFile->SendRequest();
```

P.S. The main issue is that server must reject two similar requests. But it accepts with them if they are sent one by one (without an exit from my program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason. The debugger in visual studio doesn't support the debugging when programmer uses flags such as INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD